# turn array hex colors into array rgb colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach, each

I have an array of hex colors like this:

```
var hexColors = [
    "#ffffff",
    "#ffffff",
    "#ffffff",
    "#f3f3f3",
    "#f3f3f3",
    "#f3f3f3"];
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
var rgbColors = new Array(
[62,35,255],
[60,255,60],
[255,35,98],
[45,175,230],
[255,0,255],
[255,128,0]);
```

using this function :

```
 function hexToRgb(hex) {
 var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
 hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
    return r + r + g + g + b + b;
 });
 var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
 return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
 } : null;
}
```

How can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overcomplicate this: there's no need to run over the target string with regex *twice*. It's enough to extract all the info at the first iteration. Like this:

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
  var res = hex.match(/[a-f0-9]{2}/gi);
  return res && res.length === 3
    ? res.map(function(v) { return parseInt(v, 16) })
    : null;
}
```

The function is ready to be use in another `.map`, giving the results you want.

```
var hexColors = [
    "#ffffff",
    "#ffffff",
    "#ffffff",
    "#f3f3f3",
    "#f3f3f3",
    "#f3f3f3"
];
var rgbColors = hexColors.map(hexToRgb);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/193003)

Comment: My god! I still have a lot to study and learn! It works perfectly! Thank u so much!

Comment: How would you go about changing this function to do the opposite? changing an rgb array i.e `[255, 255, 255]` into `#FFFFFF`

Answer (score 2):

```
var hex = 'ffaadd';   
var rgb = parseInt(hex, 16);    

var red   = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;   
var green = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;     
var blue  = rgb & 0xFF;
```

Bit Operator makes it more smart ass, in both efficiency and readability.